# Where did these profiles in Visual Studio Team Explorer come from and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, team-explorer

Where did these "profiles" in the team explorer come from and how do I get rid of them? In one of my projects there are files seemingly split across multiple of these, and I don't know what they are, how they got there, or how to get rid of them.

[image]

Comment: Did you check if what you have are multiple work spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all the different work spaces that are created on your local machine. A workspaces is a local copy of your code base. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383.aspx)

This tends to happen if you re-install or upgrade Visual Studio. At this point it is best if you do a cleanup, by deleting workspaces. However, be **very very careful** since there is a good chance that you will lose code that is not checked in.